# Affectiva emotion SDK - Unable to process a webm file using VideoDetector

Tags: windows, opencv, image-processing, emotion, affdex-sdk

I am currently developing a program using the Windows SDK.

I'm trying to feed a ".webm" file into the SDK, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Encountered an AffdexException Error opening video file: C:\1.webm                                    
Source: __thiscall FileVideoCapture::FileVideoCapture(const class boost::filesystem::path &,const float)(C:\Jenkins\workspace\affdexface-win32\src\modules\utils\FileVideoCapture.cpp LINE 12)
```

This occurs when I use the `.process(path_to_file)` method of the `VideoDetector` class.

I'm guessing it has something to do with OpenCV because the VideoCapture class is apart of OpenCV.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `VideoDetector` class uses FFmpeg in order to access video codecs.

Please make sure that the `opencv_ffmpeg.dll` is loadable by your application either by copying it to your application binary folder or by adding it’s location to your `PATH` environment variable.

The dll is included in the sdk archive under the bin directory.

Comment: Well, I have exactly the same error (the only difference is I load an .avi file). I tried both to add the location of opencv_ffmpeg.dll to the PATH environment and to copy it in the binary folder but without any success...

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that your video use a good container but not a good codec. You can check the [list of supported formats](http://developer.affectiva.com/supportedvideoformats/).
In my case I use a .avi with FMP4 codec. It should be supported but I got the same error as you. I reencoded the video with another codec and now it works.